# Encoding linear hybrid automata using z3 python API

Tags: python, python-2.7, z3

I am trying to encode linear hybrid automata as conjunction of first order formulas as follows:

```
s.add(Or(Or(And(off,Not(on),Not(S1),Not(S2),(10*x_next)>=(3*t1)-(3*t2)+(10*x),(10*x_next)<=(10*x)-(t2-t1),x_next>=18,(t2-t1)>0,Implies(),
And(Not(off),on,Not(S2),Not(S1),(10*x_next)>=(t2-t1)+(10*x),(5*x_next)<=(5*x)+(t2-t1),x_next<=22,(t2-t1)>0)),    
Or(And(x<19,(t2-t1)==0,S1,Not(off),Not(on),Not(S2),(x-x_next)==0),
And(x>21,(t2-t1)==0,Not(on),Not(off),S2,Not(S1),(x-x_next)==0))))
```

The problem is jump conditions (e.g. if x<19 then ....) needs to be taken, which doesnt seem to work here.
Can somebody help me to encode jump conditions as a conjunction of first order formulas using z3 python API?

Comment: What do you mean by a jump condition? Could you provide more details?

Comment: Hybrid automata consists of different modes.Each mode has to satisfy certain linear arithmetic constraints. But if the value of state variable in a particular mode reaches a certain value (e.g x<19) , then a jump is taken and the new set of linear constraints has to be satisfied.

Comment: In this case there only to modes (off,on). if (x<19) then automaton has to switch to on.On the other hand if the HA is in on mode and x<21, it has to take a jump to the off mode. This all process has to be in conjunction of FOL formulas. I hope i have explained it.

Comment: Two modes (on,off). HA starts in off mode.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to look for or construct a tool that can encode 
HA formulas from a higher-level description. They can help debugging some details. 
For example, you say there are two modes "on" and "off". These appear to be encoded as propositional variables. Typically one uses a program counter to encode the state of an automaton, so for example there would be a program counter "state" whose values can be either "on" or "off". You can use scalars in Z3 to encode the possible values of state variables or you can use integers, or bit-vectors or in this case a Boolean flag.
Then there is a question of encoding transition relations. You will typically need to encode the frame condition on variables that are not changed by transitions.

Comment: Thats true that the two modes are encoded as proposiional variables.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit more. Actually there are two sets of linear arithmaeic constraints for each mode (They can be epresented as disjunction of first order formulas). The real issue that i am facing is how to do switching between these two sets(or two modes) of constaints.The swithcing has to be an integral part of the final fomula.

Comment: s.add(off,Not(on),(10*x_next)>=(3*t1)-(3*t2)+(10*x),(10*x_next)<=(10*x)-(t2-t1),x_next>=18,(t2-t1)>0                         This is how i have implemented consriants for "off" mode